# Derived and Base type differentiation

Tags: c#

Lets say that we have the following code

```
Base() { ... }

Derived : Base { ... }

Main() 
{
    var derivedInstance = new Derived();

    if(derivedInstance is Base)
    {
         DoStuff();
    }
}
```

The if statement that we have returns true.  How do I differentiate between the derived type from the base type when I am working with a derived instance.

Essentially, I want the above if statement to return false, but not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: this is how OO works: a derived class by extending the base class IS usable everywhere the base class is expected, thus Derived IS Base.

Comment: @vulkanino. But some times you do want to check the type... Like with `Equals` metohd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
if (derivedInstance.GetType() == typeof(Base)) {
    DoStuff();
}
```

However, this looks rather strange. What are you trying to do?
What about having a virtual method defined in your base class:

```
class Base { 
    public virtual void DoStuff() {
        // actually do something
    }
}
class Derived { 
    public virtual override void DoStuff() {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

And then you could just call `DoStuff()` on the instance, without checking its type.

Comment: This is exactly what I need.  I'm doing a database save operation, I check the type and do a save against it, problem was, the save op was saving it as a base type rather than a derived type.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `typeof` which checks what is the type of the instance.

```
if (derivedInstance.GetType() == typeof(Base)) 
{
    DoStuff();
}
```

`is` checks if the instance is of that type **or derived from it** (or implements the `Interface` if the parameter is an `Interface`)

[MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> The is operator is used to check whether the run-time type of an object is compatible with a given type. The is operator is used in an expression of the form